# The mailbox that was requested doesn't support the specified RequestServerVersion

Tags: email, send, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to send an email using Exchange Web Services.

Below is the code:

```cs
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
service.Url = new Uri("https://mail.mydomain.com/ews/Exchange.asmx");
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("Username", "Password", "Domain");
EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
message.Subject = "SEND!";
message.Body = "Please work.";
message.Sender = new EmailAddress("myemailaddress@mydomain.com");
message.ToRecipients.Add("myemailaddress@mydomain.com");
message.Save();

message.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

But I'm getting the below error:

> "The mailbox that was requested doesn't support the specified RequestServerVersion"

Help?

Comment: What version is your Exchange Server? Either the server version you passed (`ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010`) is incorrect, or the mailbox version needs updated.